# Php foreach loop inserts only part of records into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql database I get ONLY the records for id 26, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24. Why is that, is there any error in my code? I don;t have a clue, please help:(

```
<?
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbname', 'pass');  
if (!$connect) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE anchors");

$blog_ids = array(
'anchor 1' => '1', 
'anchor 2' => '2', 
'anchor 3' => '3', 
'anchor 2' => '4',  
'anchor 2' => '5',  
'anchor 4' => '6',  
'anchor 5' => '7',  
'anchor 6' => '8', 
'anchor 7' => '9',  
'anchor 8' => '10', 
'anchor 9' => '13',
'anchor 10' => '14',
'anchor 11' => '16',
'anchor 12' => '17', 
'anchor 13' => '18', 
'anchor 14' => '20', 
'anchor 15' => '21', 
'anchor 16' => '22', 
'anchor 17' => '23', 
'anchor 18' => '24', 
'anchor 19' => '25', 
'anchor 20' => '26' 
);
foreach($blog_ids as $anchor => $blog_id){
$anchor_url = 'http://www.site.com';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO anchors (blog_id, anchor_url, anchor) VALUES ('$blog_id', '$anchor_url', '$anchor')");
} 

mysql_close($connect); 
?>
```

Ty very much, here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `anchors` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `blog_id` text,
 `anchor_url` text,
 `anchor` text,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `posttitle` (`blog_id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: For the love of God don't kill your database with all those queries. Create one huge, combined `INSERT` sentence containing all the data (`INSERT INTO tbl (x, y) VALUES ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (...))` or at the very least use prepared statements.

Comment: Hello Kristian, I'm a newb, you are saying not to use a foreach loop? Ty very much

Comment: Yes. It's equivalent to moving a pile of paper from one table to another, one sheet at a time, instead moving the entire pile all together. It's a lot of unnecessary traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the query actually can be executed.

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO anchors (blog_id, anchor_url, anchor) VALUES ('$blog_id', '$anchor_url', '$anchor')") === FALSE) {
    echo 'failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
```

Furthermore, what is the table structure like? `SHOW CREATE TABLE anchors;` will help you. If you have a unique or primary key set, the value really needs to be unique and duplicates fail with an error.

**Edit**: The problem is not within the script, but within the data. In order to have the data in PHP, the storage needs to be adjusted.

```
$blog_ids = array(
  array(
    'anchor' => 'anchor 1',
    'blog_id' => '1'
  ),
  array(
    'anchor' => 'anchor 2',
    'blog_id' => '2'
  ),
  …
);

foreach ($blog_ids as $blog_id_array) {
  $blog_id = $blog_id_array['blog_id'];
  $anchor = $blog_id_array['anchor'];
  $anchor_url = 'http://www.site.com';

  if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO anchors (blog_id, anchor_url, anchor) VALUES ('$blog_id', '$anchor_url', '$anchor')") === FALSE) {
    echo 'failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there,CREATE TABLE `anchors` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `blog_id` text,
 `anchor_url` text,
 `anchor` text,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `posttitle` (`blog_id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: That looks fine so far. What output do you get from `mysql_error()`? Are there queries which fail?

Comment: No erros aslo, this is really strange :(. It's strange how In my table the last foreach value is first.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($blog_ids)`. In your example, you have duplicate keys. PHP does not support that. Using a key which is already present will overwrite the old value with the new one. The old value is lost then.

Comment: Ty shi, ver should I put it? inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Put it before the `foreach` and right after the array definition.

Comment: I have added it, and got this when I execute the script for every value I wrote about: array(9) { ["anchor20"]=> string(2) "26", tho I have the same problem :(

Comment: So the problem is not with your script but with your data. The array contains only 9 different elements. And all those 9 elements can be inserted into the database without an error.

Comment: How can i modify the script so i can make it work with this data, it's esential for a interlinking script I am making, using anchor texts. And if will happen that I'll have the same anchor text used multiple times, simulated in the example above

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment, but it's a bit too long. If you run something like this and get errors, edit your original question to reflect what you've found. If you also post a comment on this answer, I can try to edit this answer to solve your problem.

For INSERT statements, [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns `FALSE` on errors. You should check to see if any errors exist. I would edit your code to look more like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO anchors (blog_id, anchor_url, anchor) VALUES ('$blog_id', '$anchor_url', '$anchor')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In deployment, I wouldn't necessarily `die()`, but log errors to some reporting mechanism or parse through `mysql_error()` and return a secure and friendly error message that doesn't reveal too much about the underlying database system or queries executed.